# QSemaphore - implementing overwrite policy

Tags: multithreading, qt

I want to implement ring buffer for classic `Producer`--`Consumer` interaction. In the future both `P` and `C` will be implemented as permanent threads running during data processing task, and GUI will be the third thread only for displaying actual data and coordinate starts and stops of data processing by user interaction. `C` can be quite slow to be able to fully process all incoming data, but only a bit and for a short periods of time. So I want to just allocate ring buffer of several `P`'s MTUs in size, but in any case, if `C` will be too slow to process existing data it's okay to loose old data in favor of new one (*overwrite* policy).

I've read `QSemaphore` example in Qt help and realized that by usage of semaphore's acquires and releases I can only implement *discard* policy, because acquiring of specified chunk in queue will block until there are no free space.

Are there any ways of implementing *overwrite* policy together with `QSemaphore` or I just need to go and implement another approach?

Comment: Maybe instead of above use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html and for each enqueue() control the max size of the queue by popping items still not taken by consumer.

Comment: do you suggest using qqueue instead of semaphore completely or just as a container for data storage? If you mean the latter I afraid that I'm forced to use provided library's ring buffer for data storage. If you mean the former, how should I achieve synchronization? Mutex approach is one of the possible ways but it blocky and will decrease performance

Comment: Every write and read to-from the queue should be mutex protected. First try and then see what performance is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came to this solution. If we should push portion of the src data to the ring buffer at any costs (it's ok to drop possible newly incoming data) we should use `acquire()` in Producer part - that would provide us *discard* policy. In case we need *overwrite* policy we should use `tryAcquire()` in Producer - thus at the very first possible moment of time only the newest data will be pushed to the ring buffer

Comment: have you considered wait conditions? Qt has some examples on that topic here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html

Comment: It will not help, I think, because the core of the problem - discard immediately or wait until some free space will appear - remains the same. With the wait conditions I can push my data from Producer as soon as some specific portion will be freed in ring buffer, however, it doesn't solve discard/overwrite dilemma